# Sum label values in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

Basically, when a day is selected, I will enter each employee's time started and the time ended and their break time, and also enter their output for the day.

When the next day is selected I want to do the exact calculation for that given day and tabulate in the last three columns.

```
Option Explicit

Dim hour1 As Date
Dim hour2 As Date
Dim hour3 As Date
Dim Totalhour As Date
Dim StartNumber As Integer
Dim EndNumber As Integer
Dim Sum As Double
Dim i As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim Total As Double

Private Sub cmdHoursWorked_Click()

If OpMon.Value = True Then

hour1 = txtTimeIn1.Text
hour2 = txtTimeOut1.Text
hour3 = cmbBreak1.Text
Total = txtUnitCom1.Text
Totalhour = ((hour2 - hour1) - hour3)
lblHrsWorked1.Caption = Round((Totalhour * 24), 2)
lblMon1.Caption = Round(((lblHrsWorked1.Caption * 3600) / txtUnitCom1.Text), 1)
'lblUnitWeek1.Caption = txtUnitCom1.Text'
'lblTHW1.Caption = lblHrsWorked1'

ElseIf OpWed.Value = True Then

hour1 = txtTimeIn1.Text
hour2 = txtTimeOut1.Text
hour3 = cmbBreak1.Text
Totalhour = ((hour2 - hour1) - hour3)
lblHrsWorked1.Caption = Round((Totalhour * 24), 2)
lblWed1.Caption = Round(((lblHrsWorked1.Caption * 3600) / txtUnitCom1.Text), 1)
'lblUnitWeek1.Caption = txtUnitCom1.Text'
'lblHrsWorked1.Caption = lblTHW1.Caption'
lblSecUnit1.Content = (lblMon1.Caption + lblTue1.Caption + lblWed1.Caption + lblThu1.Caption + lblFri1.Caption)

End If

End Sub
```

Say if I select Monday, I will enter 9:00 and 17:30 as start and End Time with 30 minutes break. And I enter 500 into the units completed textbox. I then calculate the hours worked (label) and also calculate the units completed per second on the label Monday label.

Now if another day is selected I want to do exact same calculations and also adding to the last three columns based on the input from the user

```
ElseIf OpTue.Value = True Then
    start_time = CDate(txtTimeIn1.Text)
    end_time = CDate(txtTimeOut1.Text)
    break_time = CInt(cmbBreak1.Text)
    units = CSng(txtUnitCom1.Text)
    ttl_secUnit1 = CSng(lblSecUnit1.Caption)
    sec_Mon1 = CSng(lblMon1.Caption)
    'sec_Tue1 = CSng(lblTue1.Caption)

   ' Calculation
    hours_worked = (CSng(end_time) - CSng(start_time)) * 24! - break_time / 60!
    rate = units / (3600! * hours_worked)
    ttl_secUnit1 = (CSng(sec_Mon1) + CSng(sec_Tue1))
    lblSecUnit1.Caption = WorksheetFunction.Sum(lblMon1.Caption, lblTue1.Caption)


    ' Results
    lblHrsWorked1.Caption = Round((hours_worked), 2)
    lblTue1.Caption = Format(rate, "0.000")
    'lblSecUnit1.Caption = Format(ttl_secUnit1, "0.000")

End If
```

Comment: You're attempting to put text into a date variable. You need to convert it into a date first using the Cdate() function. So hour1 = cdate(txtTimeIn1.Text)

Comment: Note that each `.Caption` is a string so **don't** do things like `lblSecUnit1.Caption = WorksheetFunction.Sum(lblMon1.Caption, lblTue1.Caption)`, Math should be done on numeric types (integers and floats) as I indicate in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing math with strings and hoping VBA interpreter does what you intended. Don't do that. Instead, handle the data in three distinct steps:

1. Take the inputs from the labels and convert them into values of type `Integer`, `Single`, or `Date` using either `CInt()`, `CSng()` or `CDate()`.
2. Do the math with the values.
3. Convert the values into strings using the `Format()` function for display.

In the simple example below

[image: output]

```
Public Sub CalculateRate()

    ' Input values
    Dim start_time As Date, end_time As Date
    Dim break_time As Integer, units As Single

    start_time = CDate(Label1.Caption)
    end_time = CDate(Label2.Caption)
    break_time = CInt(Label3.Caption)
    units = CSng(Label4.Caption)

    ' Calculation
    Dim hours_worked As Single, rate As Single
    hours_worked = (CSng(end_time) - CSng(start_time)) * 24! - break_time / 60!
    rate = units / (3600! * hours_worked)

    ' Results
    Label5.Caption = Format(rate, "0.000")

End Sub
```

Note that the compiler interprets the following literals

- `1000` as a `Integer` (16-bit)
- `100000` as a `Long` (32-bit)
- `1000!` as a `Single` floating point number (32-bit)
- `1000#` as a `Double` floating point number (64-bit)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and your answer. It worked as outlined. My next problem is, I want to sum the units and rate if a different times are entered for a next day into a another label as total_units for the week and total_rate for the week. I am using an option button to select the days.

Comment: @Obota - So what is your question? [SO] is not a code-writing service. [Edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56969375/edit) and be specific on the parts you cannot make work right. Use a [minimal verifiable complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I am definitely not using the site as a coding service. I am not that familiar with VBA and I'm stuck with what I'm trying to do and need. Any help will be much appreciated. I have updated my question with the code I am having trouble. Basically, each time I select a day and enter the information for the employee, I want to tabulate add to the previous days hours, rate and units for get a total for the week in three labels.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I am definitely not using the site as a coding service. I am not that familiar with VBA and I'm stuck with what I'm trying to do. Any help will be much appreciated. I have updated my question with the code I am having trouble with. Basically, each time I select a day and enter the information for the employee, I want to add to the previous days hours, rate and units for get a total for the week in three labels as total hours, total units and weekly average rate per sec.